How to connect dataset with Google Cloud Storage in Azure copy activity
We have created a linked service for Google Cloud Storage in Azure Data Factory (ADF). After that, we set up a Copy Activity to retrieve CSV files from Blob Storage. However, when configuring the sink to copy data from Azure blob storage (source) into Google Cloud Storage(sink), we found that creating a dataset using Google Cloud Storage is unavailable.
How can we handle this situation?

i want to design the pipeline , so is there any way or solution so that i can design the pipeline? because i need to transfer there updated file daily from blob to google @Bhavani

It is a limitation in Adf, you can't design pipeline with Google cloud as sink. You can check this once.

According to the MS document

As of now Google Cloud Storage supports only as Source in copy activity, it is not supported as the sink of the copy activity.

That may be the reason to not able to create a dataset using Google Cloud Storage in sink of copy activity. Alternatively, you can use GCP Data Transfer Service to copy data from Azure blob storage Google Cloud Storage, it supports MS Azure Storage container as source as shown below:

For more information, you can refer to the document.
